# How to add images to listview in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to load images to listview.
Look likes this.

[image: this]

I do not know how to add this images to listview.
When click this list item its load another activity.
Can i add this mages to list and set to adapter?

Comment: use custom list view/try lazy list view https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: This is very simple and basic, I don't think using lib :)

Answer (score 2):

In http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Instead of String Array You have to use Integer array & Put your drawable images in it.

Like this:

```
int images[] = {R.drawable.product1, R.drawable.product2, R.drawable.product3, R.drawable.product4, R.drawable.product5, R.drawable.product6, R.drawable.product7};
```

&

fetch your images in your ImageView like this:

```
imgview.setImageResource(arr[position]);
```

you are done.

Comment: I tried your answer. what about this error?02-27 16:29:12.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1702): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-27 16:29:12.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2467)
02-27 16:29:12.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
02-27 16:29:12.993: E/AndroidRuntime(1702):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)

Comment: Its says 02-27 16:39:22.963: E/AndroidRuntime(2385):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2467)
02-27 16:39:22.963: E/AndroidRuntime(2385):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
this.measureHeightOfChildren

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48566/discussion-between-sagar-shah-and-anuruddhika)

Comment: simple and clean !

Answer (score 1):

```
you need to create custom xml(only with image) for your list view and you need to set custom adapter to your list view.

    check this link this will help you.

        http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

    or try this

    Activity file:

    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {

         ImageView selectedImage;  
         private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    R.drawable.android3d,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,

            };
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                 ListView gallery = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

            gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this,R.layout.img));

             // clicklistener for Gallery
            gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your selected position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
       class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Context mContext;

        int layout ;

        public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context, int layout) 
        {
            mContext = context;
            this.layout = layout;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        // Override this method according to your need
        public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View rowView = inflater.inflate(layout, viewGroup, false);

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
                imageView.setImageResource(mImageIds[index]);


                return rowView;

        }
    }
    }

    activity_mail xml:

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/gallery1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

         </LinearLayout>

    img xml :

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In this case i want to add Image list not the String array.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of behaviour you need to implement your own adapter. As you are using an Arrayadapter you should extend Arrayadapter and overwrite the getView method to change the view of the ListItem in the way you want it to. Have a look at this ListView Tutorial for more information on this topic. `http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html`

Comment: Yes i had work with adapters. But the case is this images are dynamically change. i want to add images to list and load to adapter.

Comment: Yeah, in getView() you has a variable position, set image for your view. If u have a List<Image> images, u can get Image i = images.get(position), and set this image into your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using custom `adapter` of Items. Each item is an `ImageView` as the following example:

**MainActivity:**

```
this.adapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, R.layout.items_list_item, ItemManager.getLoadedItems());
setListAdapter(this.adapter);
```

And create the following `adapter` class:

**ItemsAdapter:**

```
private class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private Item[] items;

public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Item[] items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_list_item, null);
    }

    Item it = items[position];
    if (it != null) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_image);
        if (iv != null) {
            iv.setImageDrawable(it.getImage());
        }
    }

    return v;
}
}
```

Then add your desired action in the `onItemClickListener`

Comment: what about this getSystemService and getImage() method?

Comment: It display this error. The method getImage() is undefined for the type ClipData.Item

Comment: @anuruddhika, `Item` is a user defined object. Create a class called Item and do the setter and the getters for it :)